# aws lambda python socket issue

Tags: python, sockets, amazon-web-services, ssl, lambda

```
import time
import datetime
import socket
import ssl
all_ip = ["cert-name1", "cert-name2","cert-name3","cert-name4"]

def ssl_expiry_datetime(hostname):
    ssl_date_fmt = r'%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z'
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    conn = context.wrap_socket(
        socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
        server_hostname=hostname,
    )

    conn.connect((hostname, 443))
    ssl_info = conn.getpeercert()
    # parse the string from the certificate into a Python datetime object
    today_date = time.strftime(r'%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')
    b = datetime.datetime.strptime(ssl_info['notAfter'], ssl_date_fmt)
    print b - datetime.datetime.utcnow()


def lambda_handler(event,context):
    for hostname in all_ip:
        ssl_expiry_datetime(hostname)
```

My code was this ,if i pass 3 certs it was working but when i add my 4th cert in that list i was getting time out error from 4th cert!!1 amy i doing anything wrong in my code?
Please help, thanks.

Comment: If you swap hosts 3 and 4, does the timeout happen on the 3rd or the 4th?

Comment: still i was getting error. it doesn't matterwhat ever host it is. it works only for first 3 rest all getting timeout error.